# in longtable a Bold \cline and colored column

Tags: longtable, cline, cellcolor

I have a longtable with some thick horizontal lines (I know and agree, lines are ugly, but I have to do it). Works good with package boldline and \clineB. But it interferes with colored Columns.

Am I able to fix this?

The example is completely stripped, in realiter it is much more complex, with some codechange in \LT@output for footer and header value-overflows

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{boldline}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}r}
\newcolumntype{G}[1]{>{\columncolor{Gray}}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}|p{2cm}|G{3cm}|c|}\hline
Ueb1 & Ueb2 & Ueb3\\\hline
Zeile1 & Inhalt & Inhalt\\\hline
Zeile2 & Inhalt & Inhalt\\\clineB{1-1}{4}\clineB{2-2}{6}\clineB{3-3}{4}
Zeile3 & Inhalt & Inhalt\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

i have seen this (https://golatex.de/problem-mit-cline-und-hintergrundfarbe-von-spalten-t12684.html), but I could get the soulutions to work with my setup.

Comment: Do you want a thick rule in the coloured column, or no rule at all?

Comment: I want a thicker line in the coloured column  than in the other two the left and right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Boldline`, and the bold lines from `makecell` have problems with colour in tables. For  lines of variable widths, you can load `booktabs` and neutralise locally the padding added around the rules, or use the `\specialrule` command, which lets you set the width, padding above and padding below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{boldline}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}r}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{}|c|g|c|}\hline
Ueb1 & Ueb2 & Ueb3\\\hline
Zeile1 & Inhalt & Inhalt\\\hline
Zeile2 & Inhalt & Inhalt\\
\specialrule{1.6pt}{0pt}{0pt}%
Zeile3 & Inhalt & Inhalt\\\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you want a horizontal rule to have a varying width (depending on the column), it's easy to obtain with  booktabs `\cmidrule`s, but this will result in gaps in the vertical rules. So I suggest a plain `\hline` with a series of convenient `\hhline`s above and below, like this code

```
\begin{longtable}{@{}|p{2cm}|G{3cm}|c|}
\hline
Ueb1 & Ueb2 & Ueb3\\\hline
Zeile1 & Inhalt & Inhalt\\\hline
Zeile2 & Inhalt & Inhalt\\
\hhline{|~|-|~|}
\hhline{|~|-|~|}
\hline
\hhline{|~|-|~|}
\hhline{|~|-|~|}
Zeile3& Inhalt & Inhalt \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
```

[image]

Comment: can I use \specialrule in combination with \cline?

Comment: I want a thicker line in the coloured column  than in the other two the left and right.

Comment: Oh! I see. I'll try to post something  in a moment.

Comment: ah, and btw, I have changed the example to a p{}-column, so I do not know the height?

Comment: @PeterMiehle: I've added a code based on `hhline` (looks like a hack, but I found no other way to obtain this result). Is it what you try to achieve?